# Retrieve E-mail from server (pop3) by date for filtering on subject or body in C#

Tags: c#, email, httpwebrequest, pop3

I have a piece of monitoring software I am writing which needs to retrieve e-mails sent to an address for a certain day so that I can filter them by a regex in the subject or body.  I don't need to retrieve the entire message, only the subject and body for all messages on a given day so that I can evaluate them with a regular expression for a token.

I looked at [EAGetMail](http://www.emailarchitect.net/webapp/popcom/developers/csharp.asp) as a solution, but their implementation doesn't do what I need to to do.  I can only get all information on mail, which only has the size and index.  I would need it by subject, but even then I don't want to get everything in inbox. If I went with this solution I have to get all mail, and then retrieve each mail message individually to evaluate the subject and body.  This is not ideal.

I also looked at [OpenPop.Net](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/), but it too does not have a targeted retrieval for today's messages only.

Can I even do what I want without looping through every single email on the server until I find a match?  What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  Am I going to have to build a custom web request to get the data I want?  Also, I looked at [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/default.asp), but I am looking for a free solution, even if it means building the http request myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know if this helps you at all because it is vb.net however, if you combine with the other link it may help.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/EmailClient.aspx